# Index scan on primary key(ID)

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Query

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Product
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Skv5OqZBU

Why optimizer uses index scan even if query is based on primary key(ID) ?

Comment: Upload your plan xml to [Past The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question instead of as an image link.

Comment: What plan would you expect to be more optimal? Only the first row is read, reading the index backwards.

Comment: I would expect index seek not index scan

Comment: Seek on what value? There is no WHERE clause in the query. Examine the clustered index scan operator and you will see it's an ordered backwards scan. The TOP operator requests a single row. Consequently, the value returned will be the max value in the table and retrieved most optimally.

Comment: So basically if there is a specific id value which needs to be searched in a query uses index seek

Comment: Yes, a key value is needed so that the storage engine knows where to begin the scan of the index at the seek starting point. Assuming ID is an integer, you'll see a seek with the plan being effectively the same with `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.Product WHERE ID <= 2147483647;`, However, the seek starting at the highest possible value serves no useful purpose when the intent is to start at the end anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the details inside the "index scan" node of your plan, you will find that it only expects 1 row returned. Scanning for 1 row from the end in fact has a better performance than an index seek.

The physical structure of a MSSQL index is a B+ tree. By index seek, it means you starts from the tree part to locate the item in O(log N). By index scan, it means you starts from the data part to locate the items. This time you read one, so it is O(1).

So your query is in fact performing very fast now.